# How to change underline thickness in PDF using adobe?

Tags: windows-10, pdf, adobe-acrobat

My underline thickness is too thin. I want to change the line to be thicker. Searching web, I was expected that thickness should be an option on right lick on the underlined text and bring properties but I don't have that option. (I see screen shots of that on Mac has this option).

I am using Adobe Acrobat Reader DC (20.012.20048) on Windows 10. So how can I change the thickness?

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure out this? I have the same problem... :(

Comment: @dontpanic nopes, maybe there is some trick, don't know of any way to do that through user interface.